# Transform local img into Base64 string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an img in my project (/Content/Img/myPic.png) and i need to transform it into base 64 and save it in a string variable.

Something like:

```
let myFile = File("/Content/Img/myPic.png");
let fileBase64 = Base64Transformer(myFile);
```

I don't know how to access my file, and what to use to transform it.
Any idea?

Comment: In modern browsers, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript#answer-20285053 seems to be what you are after

Comment: Ok but how can i access the file to give it to window.btoa() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try - [angular-file-to-base64-directive](https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload), it takes a `input` file and preduce a `base64`.

Ouput example :

```
{
    "filesize": 54836, /* bytes */
    "filetype": "image/jpeg",
    "filename": "profile.jpg",
    "base64":   "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD//gAEKgD/4gIctcwIQA..."
  }
```